# Creating new files with custom ContentsManager in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm writing a custom [ContentsManager](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/contents.html) manager for Jupyter Notebooks and gotten to creating new files.

Originally my `file_exists` function always returned `True` and I've gotten `Cannot POST to files, use PUT instead` error, same as [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/15).

Following that I amended `file_exists` function to return `False`, however now Jupyter is stuck in the loop calling `file_exists` with:

```
/dir
/dir/Untitled.ipynb
/dir/Untitled1.ipynb
/dir/Untitled2.ipynb
...
```

My question is - what should I return from `file_exists` so that notebook creation goes along?

I though maybe `get` or `save` get called after `file_exists` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exist` - false

`exist_dir` for dir - true

`exist_dir` for file - false

That's the ticket.